# ajax code to check new records at database

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

I am using laravel, and I want to check if there are new records inserted into the database, I want an Ajax code the returns with the result, I don't know ajax so please help me

this is my controller
public function newrecord($target_id){

```
    $record = Message::where('target_id', $target_id)->get();
    return $record->count();

}**strong text**
```

and this is my ajax code
$(document).ready(function(){

```
                            var ajaxCall=function()
                            {
                                $.ajax({
                                    url:"{{ url('/record/'.$auth->id) }}" ,
                                    type: "GET",
                                    datatype:"html",
                                    data:{},


                                     success:function(data) {

                                    $('.msgnum').html(data)

                                     console.log('new record);
                                      },
                                     error: function(data) {

                                    console.log('error');
                                 }
                                 });
                            }
                            setInterval(ajaxCall,5000);

    });
```

all I get is just a loop or " new record " in the console log

Do I need to return anything to tell that there is a new file, any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, of course modify the code to how you want it to work but wrap the whole thing in `setInterval`, you don't even need the `document.ready()`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url:"{{ url('/record/'.$auth->id) }}",
        type: "GET",
        datatype:"html",
        data:{},
        processData:false,
        success: function(data){
            $('.msgnum').html(data)
            console.log('new record');
            error: function(data) {
                console.log('error');
            }
        },
        error: function(){}
    });
}, 5000);
</script>
```